# Android Marshmallow: How to manually sleep+lock OR manually sleep without locking?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, sleep

I am using Android 6 (Cyanogenmod) and I would like to have the following simple behaviour:

Hardware button X: **Sleep AND lock** the phone.

Hardware button Y: **Sleep phone WITHOUT locking**.

In addition I do not want ANY automatic locking/unlocking going on.

That seems to be impossible. If so, that's clearly a design fault.

Please enlighten me with your Android expertise.

TY

Comment: First one is definitely doable using [Xposed Additions](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spazedog.xposed.additionsgb&hl=en).

Comment: So you are basically  saying it's only possible with mods?

Comment: Might be even doable with *Tasker* and *Secure Settings* – but will most likely require the device to be rooted.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested the following solution successfully on Nexus 6 running CM13 (a snapshot build) with volume rockers as HW key X and Y.

If you don't want to use an Xposed module such as Xposed Additions, then I suggest you setup [AutoInput](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoinput) (free trial) and [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) ([free trial](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/download.html); [user guide](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/)). You must have the accessibility service of AutoInput enabled and root access enabled under Developer options and already granted to Tasker.

### Instructions for Tasker

1. Create an Event based profile from Plugin →  AutoInput →  Key → Configuration:

   - Keys: your key X
   - Key Action: Key Down
2. Setup a task for it with following actions:

   1. Plugin → AutoInput  → Modes:

      - Configuration:

        - Key Suppress: Enable
        - Keys: your key X
      - Timeout: None
   2. Code → Run Shell:

      - Command: `settings put secure lock_screen_lock_after_timeout 0; input keyevent 26`
      - tick Use Root
   3. Plugin → AutoInput  → Modes:

      - Configuration:

        - Key Suppress: Disable
        - Keys: your key X
      - Timeout: None
3. Create an another Event based profile from Plugin →  AutoInput →  Key → Configuration:

   - Keys: your key Y
   - Key Action: Key Down
4. Setup a task for it with following actions:

   1. Plugin → AutoInput  → Modes:

      - Configuration:

        - Key Suppress: Enable
        - Keys: your key Y
      - Timeout: None
   2. Code → Run Shell:

      - Command: `settings put secure lock_screen_lock_after_timeout <ms>; input keyevent 26`
      - tick Use Root 

        Replace `<ms>` with milliseconds. This is the timeout available under Lock screen settings and I've not tested it beyond 1800000.
   3. Plugin → AutoInput  → Modes:

      - Configuration:

        - Key Suppress: Disable
        - Keys: your key Y
      - Timeout: None

All of the said instructions would bring to fruition only when the lock screen is secured. Furthermore, during testing I had to temporarily give up the original functionality of my HW keys.

**Note**: disable the action for disabling key suppress if you find that the actions are not working properly.